# IFrame mic flash authorization content out of visible area

Tags: css, iframe

I have the problem that an IFrame (cross domain) shows the flash authorization window to use Microphones, shifted to the left. The rest of the iframe works fine, just the auhtorization. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Flash off]

When debugging I noticed that the iframe applies the following CSS:

```
<object id="_speakpipe_flash_recorder" width="1" height="1" ...
style="left: -113px; top: 1px; width: 230px; height: 150px;">
```

Cross domain CSS injection via jQuery doesn't work. I can resize the parent div in any way, but it will always be slightly off.
The page is setup in two columns using flexbox.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38yg8gfL/ (Tho I think flash doesn't work there somehow...)

CSS:

```
.equalbox {

    display: flex;

}

.equalcol {

    margin: 5px;

    padding: 5px 25px;

    border-style: solid;

    border-width: 5px;

    border-color: #3285A8;

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also noticed that the flash authorization dynamically sets these style values on load. So somehow it believe it needs to put the window to the left...

Comment: Well it looks like the problem is elsewhere as the fiddle seem to work without issues... sorr for that!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to remove the accordion. Somehow the jQuery accordion made the Flash applet think it needs to move to the side somehow...